# Where can I find Zero Brush in Blender

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender. I just download it and start my learning here. I have question about Grease Pencil...I don't see Zero Brush menu when I press my short cut key "T" and I don't see it in my search menu either...Please guide me through it if you know thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a commercial addon you can find at BlenderSensei.com - you need to buy it and install separately.
https://blendersensei.com/zero-brush/